# Use to Chrome Store Publishing API with OAuth2 Service Account

Tags: python, google-oauth, google-chrome-app, chrome-web-store

I try to update a chrome app programmatically by using the [Chrome Web Store Publishing API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api).

I need to use a server to server authentication method and therefor created an oauth2 service account on the [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) for my project. And downloaded the credentials as key.p12.

I then try to use the [Google API Client for Python](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client). Even though the API does not support the Chrome Web Store, it should be possible to use parts of it.

I created a small script in Python to try to get a list of my Chrome Web Store items:

```
"""Creates a connection to Google Chrome Webstore Publisher API."""

from apiclient.discovery import build
import httplib2
from oauth2client import client

import os

SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL = (
    '_SOME_126736126931_RUBISH_@developer.gserviceaccount.com')

def getservice():
    # get relative path to p12 key
  dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
  filename = os.path.join(dir, 'key.p12')

  # Load the key in PKCS 12 format that you downloaded from the Google APIs
  # Console when you created your Service account.
  f = file(filename, 'rb')
  key = f.read()
  f.close()

  # Create an httplib2.Http object to handle our HTTP requests and authorize it
  # with the Credentials. Note that the first parameter, service_account_name,
  # is the Email address created for the Service account. It must be the email
  # address associated with the key that was created.
  credentials = client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
      SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      key,
      scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly')
  http = httplib2.Http()
  http = credentials.authorize(http)

  response = http.request('https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/[___my_chrome_webstore_app_id___]')

  print response
```

Even though the **authentication** towards https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly is **successful**, the response results in a **403** error.

My questions:

1. Does the 403 occur, because the service account does not have acces to my google chrome webstore items?
2. Is it possible to authenticate and use the Chrome Store API without using my personal account, that publishes into the web store (but the connected service account)?
3. How could I retrieve a valid authToken to use for the Chrome Web Store API without having a user to authenticate through the `flow`.

Comment: wondering with the refresh token, is the service account still necessary? namely with this [Github action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/chrome-extension-upload-publish) we can just keep refreshing it with a fresh token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were actually two problems with my script.

1. User

   a) To get the service account to act on behalf of the user, who published an item to the chrome web store, you need to add a sub parameter, when creating the credentials:

   > credentials = client.SignedJwtAssertionCredentials(
   >   SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL, key, scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore.readonly', sub='the.user.who.published.the.item@gmail.com')

   b) If the user is part of a Google Apps Domain, the Chrome Web Store Publish API needs to be granted access to domain wide users at the [Google Apps Dashboard > Security > Extended Settings > Manage API access](https://admin.google.com/_YOURDOMAIN.COM_/ManageOauthClients)
2. The [API call to get an item](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/get) has a required query parameter `projection` with the values `draft` or `published`. It's stated as optional in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/get), but it's actually required.

With these two changes, the API can be used with the http object. Thanks to all of you, who helped me find the solution, and to Google support, who pointed out the parameter to be required.

Comment: Thanks for this! Adding the `?projection=DRAFT` to the Items GET API URL did the trick and instead of 403 I got 200 :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Does the 403 occur, because the service account does not have acces to my google chrome webstore items?

Probably. A Service Account is **not** your own Google account.

2. Is it possible to authenticate and use the Chrome Store API without using my personal account, that publishes into the web store (but the connected service account)?

Dunno. Sorry not familiar with the Chrome Store API. You can use the Oauth Playground to test the possibilities without having to write any code.

3. How could I retrieve a valid authToken to use for the Chrome Web Store API without having a user to authenticate through the flow.

By authorizing once with "offline access", which will return you a Refresh Token. You can use that at any time, even if not logged in, to request an Access Token. As an aside, there is no such thing as an "authtoken". There is an Authorization Code and there is an Access Token. In your case, it's the Access Token you're interested in.

Comment: Thanks, do you have a link to the Oauth playground?

Comment: Thanks @pinoyyid for pointing me to the Playground, a great tool! Unfortunately I am still not able to access the chrome webstore with the Playground. I tried to do a flow authorization and gave access to my personal developer account (the one I published the chrome webstore app with). I get an auth code and an access token for the scope of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chromewebstore, but if I try the token towards https://www.googleapis.com/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/ I still get a 403. I use this guide to create headers: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#usingtheapi

Comment: try hacking some random characters into the access token, then see if the error changes from a 403 to a 401. It might help narrow down the problem. Otherwise I'm out of ideas :-(

Comment: Yes, if the token is cluttered with random characters, then the result changes to a 401. So I think the authentication is successful but I am somehow not authorized to access the item or something. I don't know how to make the connection between the Store API and my Account?

Comment: @Rias Which account is your item published under? A group publisher? An individual publisher and you're trying to log in as it?

Comment: The item is published as an individual user. First i was trying to login with a service account. But when I try and login with the individual account, i get the 403 as well.